# jQuery draggable div with an embedded div that has a click handler. How to stop the click handler from firing

Tags: jquery-ui

I have the following bit of jquery:

http://jsfiddle.net/tad604/Ck2qk/10/

I want the foo div's click handler to not fire, when you click and drag.  I've tried doing all sorts of things inside the stop/start events of the drag (event.stopPropagation() etc) all to no avail.  The click handler is fired after the drag event regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's annoying, but the only fix is to remove the event on drag start and put it back on drag stop. Try this:

```
$(".foo").click(function(){
    alert("blah");
});
$(".bar").draggable({
    stop: function(event) { setTimeout(function() {
        $(".foo").click(function(){
            alert("blah");
        }); }, 100)},
    start: function(event) { $('.foo').unbind('click'); }                
});
```

Now there is still the problem that your click events are probably a bit more complicated than this, and you probably don't want to have to rewrite them. You can save the events for later using jquery data like this:

var events = $('#test').data("events");

Alternatively, you can use jquery live function to attach the click event so the event will only ever be binded to an element that matches that selector. That means if you change the class while dragging, so that it no longer matches that selector, it would no longer have that click event. Something like this might work:

```
$(".bar .foo").live('click', function(){
    alert("blah");
});
$(".bar").draggable({
    stop: function(event) { setTimeout(function() {
    $(".draggableBar").removeClass('draggableBar').addClass('bar');
    }, 100)},
    start: function(event) { $(this).removeClass('bar').addClass('draggableBar'); }                
});
```

You'd also have to update the css so draggablebar gets the same style as bar.

Comment: That works, unfortunately my actual use case is nowhere near as simple as the contrived example I'm showing.  A pass objects to a function which makes the objects draggable and they all have their own inner elements with multiple/different onclick handlers.  Is there a way to unbind the function? and put it in some other field on the object? so that I can rebind it later?

Comment: Edited my answer with a few suggestions, hope they help!